# how to change a column contents

Tags: linux, sed

I have this input;

```
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    gene    72040   72306   0.67    -   .   g4
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    transcript  72040   72306   0.67    -   .   g4.t1
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    stop_codon  72040   72042   .   -   0   transcript_id "g4.t1"; gene_id "g4";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    CDS 72040   72306   0.67    -   0   transcript_id "g4.t1"; gene_id "g4";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    exon    72040   72306   .   -   .   transcript_id "g4.t1"; gene_id "g4";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    start_codon 72304   72306   .   -   0   transcript_id "g4.t1"; gene_id "g4";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    gene    72500   72970   0.99    -   .   g5
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    transcript  72500   72970   0.99    -   .   g5.t1
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    stop_codon  72500   72502   .   -   0   transcript_id "g5.t1"; gene_id "g5";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    CDS 72500   72970   0.99    -   0   transcript_id "g5.t1"; gene_id "g5";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    exon    72500   72970   .   -   .   transcript_id "g5.t1"; gene_id "g5";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    start_codon 72968   72970   .   -   0   transcript_id "g5.t1"; gene_id "g5";
```

I would love to have this output;

```
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    gene    72040   72306   0.67    -   .   transcript_id "g4.t1"; gene_id "g4";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    transcript  72040   72306   0.67    -   .   transcript_id "g4.t1"; gene_id "g4";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    stop_codon  72040   72042   .   -   0   transcript_id "g4.t1"; gene_id "g4";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    CDS 72040   72306   0.67    -   0   transcript_id "g4.t1"; gene_id "g4";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    exon    72040   72306   .   -   .   transcript_id "g4.t1"; gene_id "g4";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    start_codon 72304   72306   .   -   0   transcript_id "g4.t1"; gene_id "g4";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    gene    72500   72970   0.99    -   .   transcript_id "g5.t1"; gene_id "g5";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    transcript  72500   72970   0.99    -   .   transcript_id "g5.t1"; gene_id "g5";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    stop_codon  72500   72502   .   -   0   transcript_id "g5.t1"; gene_id "g5";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    CDS 72500   72970   0.99    -   0   transcript_id "g5.t1"; gene_id "g5";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    exon    72500   72970   .   -   .   transcript_id "g5.t1"; gene_id "g5";
scaffold10x_1   AUGUSTUS    start_codon 72968   72970   .   -   0   transcript_id "g5.t1"; gene_id "g5";
```

how can I use sed command on linux to get the desired output?
Thanks
Kay

Comment: @Theophrastus Beware of the `.t1`trap! And why are you escaping the quotes inside the double quotes?

Comment: so basically, the first file is the current output file have from Augustus software, but then I need to use the file as input for another software, and it seems my file does conform to what new software requires.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually a good idea to explain the replacement logic and some border conditions, so there is no need to guess. You didn't, so I have to make some assumptions:

- You want to make replacements if the last column of the line is either `g` followed by any (maybe multi-digit) number and an optional `.t1` (always `1`)
- No matter whether the line had a `.t1` or not, the `transcript_id` should be sufficed `.t1`, the `gene_id` should not
- The column delimiters are whitespaces

In this case, the following script should work. Otherwise, you need to adapt it:

`sed -E 's/ (g[0-9]*)(\.t1)?$/ transscript_id "\1.t1"; gene_id "\1";/' yourfile`

Comment: I am trying to change some contents in the last column. for every gene and transcript in a group for example, their current attribute is g4 and g4.t1 respectively. I want all the attributes in the group to have similar attribute, as 
 transcript_id "g4.t1"; gene_id "g4";

Comment: thanks, Philippos, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? I tested it to produce the output you desired, so under which condition does it fail? What does your mechanic answer if you say nothing but "my car doesn't work"?